# Inserting multiple records at once in Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am working with a .NET Core 6 minimal api with a PostgreSQL 13 database. The packages I'm using are `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 6.0.0 and `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`. I have things set to `LogLevel.Information` so that I can view the SQL queries Entity Framework Core creates as it talks to the database.

I notice that when I insert records through my endpoint that it does a series of single insert statements instead of the expected
`(VALUES (<row1 values>),(<row2 values>))` format. For example, it is logging:

```
INSERT INTO <mytable> (<columns>) VALUES (<row1 values>);
INSERT INTO <mytable> (<columns>) VALUES (<row2 values>);
```

This is my code for the insert:

```
context.Items.AddRange(list);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Is there a way for it to combine all of the values into a single `INSERT` query?

Comment: That can be done with [EFCore.BulkExtension](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) and the `BulkInsert` method. The library has fast CRUD ops (`CopyBinary` used behind) Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@svyatoslav-danyliv answer isn't accurate.

EF Core batches all inserts/updates: when you execute SaveChanges on your DbContext, all changes that have been accumulated are sent via a single command, in a single roundtrip (you can use a packet sniffer such as wireshark to observe this).

Note that this can be *more* efficient than a single INSERT query in some situations, since the multiple INSERTs statements are parameterized and have identical SQL, so the same prepared statement can be used repeatedly.

Having said that, if you're bulk-importing a huge amount of records, it may still be worth it to use Npgsql's low-level COPY support. I highly recommend writing up a quick benchmark with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) and comparing the various solutions with your own scenario.

Comment: Well, agree with that. But usually, when people have question "why they do not generate such query", they have performance issue. Also there is no way in EF Core to make fire and forget insert, especially if there are database generated fields.

Comment: Multiple roundtrips vs. one is quite a different question from "fire and forget" updates. With PostgreSQL, database-generated fields (e.g. IDs) are retrieved via a RETURNING clause, which has very little overhead beyond actually transferring the value (e.g. no extra roundtrips), so this is unlikely to be a source of perf issues. In any case there's no indication of a perf issue above, just a question about how insertion is done.

Comment: I've upvoted both question and (this answer), but it might be interesting to note that perhaps there's a difference when using EF Core with MySQL: my inserts where slow, so I switched to old ADO.NET and MySQL connector to have just one insert (rather than many inserts in a single batch, the EF way) and that cut insert time by 70%,

Comment: @FrancescoB. that sounds like something you should signal on the MySQL EF provider repo. One insert per batch should definitely not be faster than several.

Answer (score 1):

It is how EF works. You cannot insert/update/delete anything without Change Tracker. And it is not performant if there are a lot of records. PostgreSQL has [COPY](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) for inserting a bulk of records and if you are worrying about performance you can use such ability which is provided by Npgsql.

While there is a fast way for inserting records, it is very low level mechanism which requires a lot of efforts and accurate mapping to make it work.

So, there are a lot of EF Core extensions which can make it work with minimum efforts. One of them is [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), note that I'm one of the creators and my opinion can be subjective.

After installing library you can just call `BulkCopy` to insert a batch of records.

```cs
await context.BulkCopyAsync(items);
```

There are also tweaking parameters which can improve performance.

**UPDATE:**

With EF Core 7 you can use `ExecuteUpdate` and `ExecuteDelete` functions, which provides bulk operations for `Update` and `Delete`.

Comment: For the time this answer was correct but in EF Core 7 you can update and delete